# Windows 10 font size remains at 100% despite DPI being set to 150%

Tags: windows-10, fonts, dpi

As you can see on the screenshot below, despite DPI being at 150%, applications and desktop all have a tiny font, with the exception of the taskbar.

[image]

Haven't done any changes at all, just started the computer today and it looked like that.

Tried to temporarily switch to another DPI and back to 150%, rebooted but nothing.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Two Windows 10 machines and fine here. Try running DISM / SFC and restart. ......(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John Tried your suggestion, it didn't find anything, I rebooted but still no luck...

Comment: @aybe - [Have you tried just increasing the text size?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-the-size-of-text-in-windows-1d5830c3-eee3-8eaa-836b-abcc37d99b9a#ID0EBD=Windows_10)

Comment: @Ramhound You rock, that worked!!! I first set it to 150% then realized things were 150% bigger than they usually are, i.e. 225%. I set it back to 100% and rebooted; things are back to normal, i.e. they follow the 150% DPI scale. Thanks!!! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I fix that?

You can increase text size within Ease of Access > Display under Make everything bigger.

> [image]

Source: [Change the size of text in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-the-size-of-text-in-windows-1d5830c3-eee3-8eaa-836b-abcc37d99b9a#ID0EBD=Windows_10)

Comment: Whatever that corrupted that DPI thing in the registry, that simple trick fixed the issue :)